# Vue component doesn't reactively update

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I have such a simple component. And it renders fine at the first time, but when the `result` props changes nothing happens to it, all classes are still the same.

```
<template>
    <span class="icon" >
        <i :class="iconClass"></i>
    </span> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class Icon extends Vue {
        @Prop() result!: string;

        private StatusToClass: { [index: string] : string } = {
            'success': "has-text-success fas fa-check-circle",
            'warning': "has-text-warning fas fa-square",
            'noData':  "has-text-warning fas fa-square",
            'fail': "has-text-danger fas fa-exclamation-triangle",
        }

        get iconClass(){
            return this.StatusToClass[this.result];
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange, as parent to child props are reactive, so if data passed as prop changes, the prop inside child comp should update accordingly.

Perhaps, try to use a computed property, like so

```
computed: {
  iconClass () {
    return this.StatusToClass[this.result]
  }
}
```

Other problem might be with the reactivity of data itself, perhaps You're updating it wrong so it's not reactive. You should check if You're receiving the correct updated prop via Vue DevTools.

Comment: I don’t know maybe there are some problems with the awesome fonts magic. Because if i just print out these classes they are updated but not in the html output.